# How do I move a SKSpriteNode to an area outside of it's constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

So I have these moving sprites with physics bodies that I initially have constrained to one area. Let's say call this area Box1. When the sprites bump the borders of Box1, they bump back and the SKConstraint is just an additional measure to make sure they stay within the box.

What I'm trying to do is make a button that causes all the sprites in Box1 move across the screen to a second box (Box2) that is basically identical to Box1 but right beside it. Box1 and Box2 share a border wall, so essentially the screen is divided in two sections.

My problem is when I call up my button function, the sprites get stuck at the wall and aren't able to go past it to Box2. I've tried setting both the physics bodies and the SKConstraints of the nodes to nil so I don't know what else is preventing them.

```
    func moveSprites(){
    if box1Sprites.isEmpty == false {
        for sprite in box1Sprites{
            sprite.constraints = nil
            sprite.physicsBody = nil
            let moveAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: -300, y: 0), duration: 1) //This is a point within Box2
            sprite.run(moveAction)
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I also made it so that I could drag and drop the sprites from one box to the other and the code for that is pretty much the same and it works fine.

```
var currentMovingSprite: SKSpriteNode? = SKSpriteNode()

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
    let pos = touch.location(in: self)
    let node = self.atPoint(pos)
        if node.name == "sprite"{
           node.constraints = nil
           node.physicsBody = nil
           currentMovingSprite = node
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let pos = touch.location(in: self)
            if let sprite = currentMovingSprite{
                sprite.position = pos
            }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    spritePhysics(sprite: currentMovingSprite) // resets the sprite to how it was before
    currentMovingSprite = nil
}
```

Comment: Hello Alicia and welcome to SO. Why did you add the constraints - was the collision detection between the sprites and the border not working? You haven't posted enough code for us to see why the sprites won't move across, but the obvious thing to do when you hit the button to make the sprites move to the other box is to remove the border category for the boxes they are in from each sprite's `collisionbitMask` which should allow then to move through the border.

Comment: @SteveIves Yeah, I added the constraints because there would be some instances in which the collision detection would just glitch and the sprite would end up bouncing out of the box. Also, isn't the collisionbitMask related to the physicsBody? I figured that if I made the physicsBody nil, then it would also get rid of the code for the collisions but it still didn't work

Comment: The collision detection is usually pretty reliable - how are you moving the sprites? If you update their position manually (rather than by physics), then you can get glitching. Also, removing the physics body (and possibly having to re-create it) seems overkill to just prevent one specific collision.